# The script suddenly disappears after my laptop restarts itself (Controller - Laravel)

Tags: laravel, windows, powershell, model-view-controller, controller

This is my last year of vocational school. So, they are wants me to work on Laravel project. I've been working on it for 4 months and in 5 days they will check my project.

Today, I was about to check my project but then my laptop suddenly restart itself. I wasn't worry about it. But then I reopen my project, one of my controller gone, it's SiteController. I mean, the file still there but the script is gone. And the bad thing is, I didn't back up my project

I write my script on Atom. And when I open it there's only enter space on my SiteController. But when I open it on Sublime Text it turns into 0000, 0000, 0000 until 524 lines.

Also, I use Powershell. This has never happened to me before.

Comment: Lack of backups and a restart in between likely means you are going to need to rewrite this. If it's just the contents of one controller then this shouldn't be too large a task.

Comment: A good way to start "backing up" your code is to use Git.

Comment: No better time to learn to use github. Unfortunately hard way learning chosen (of two).